# Is there any way that I can access WidgetRef Ref from a function without ConsumerWidget?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to access some ref states from the top-level function. Because I can not use `FutureProvider`'s ref to get the value.

```
final SomeFunction = FutureProvider((ref) async {

  // I need to access WidgetRef to adjust the state here
  await someFunction(WidgetRef ref) {};

});
```

How can I get WidgetRef when I use FutureProvider? That `ref` works find but when I try to pass it down to the function, it does not take it as `WidgetRef`.

Comment: What do you mean "ref states"?  A WidgetRef has different but overlapping functionality with a Ref, precisely because there are different things you can do with them.  What function does a widgetref have that a ref doesn't that you think you need?

Comment: Hi! So, I want to use top-level function to access WidgetRef so that it can update some states.

Comment: Then you need to pass ref into your function.